# How to mount S3 bucket automatically on reboot

Tags: mount, startup, fstab, automount

I am using s3fs to mount an s3 bucket on my Ubuntu server:

```
sudo apt-get install s3fs

sudo vim /etc/passwd-s3fs // <--put user access key and secret key in this file

sudo chmod 640 /etc/passwd-s3fs // <-- change permission to password file

sudo vim /etc/fuse.conf // uncomment user_allow_other
```

Now mount the s3 bucket:

```
sudo s3fs -o allow_other s3-bucket-name /home/myuser/s3
```

I want to make sure that the bucket is mounted automatically after reboot, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a line to `/etc/fstab` similar to:

```
s3fs#mybucket /path/to/mountpoint fuse _netdev,allow_other 0 0
```

See other examples here:

https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse#examples